# fontawesome icon on title or author in beamer slides produces a compilation error

Tags: beamer, compilation-error, fontawesome

Since few months ago I was able to include a fontawesome icon in the title or author field of a beamer slide. With the current (and updated) version of MacTeX-2021 this seems to not work anymore. A brute-force solution is available by hitting "r" when pause on error.

A minimal working example is the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{Slides Title}
\author{Name Surname \faTwitter}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
The inclusion here of \faTwitter works fine... but including in the title or author in the titlepage produces an error (which can be solved by running over, but it is annoying).
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Which TeX engine are you using? pdfLaTeX? XeLaTeX? LuaLaTeX?

Comment: pdfLaTeX, but the same issue also happen with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

You have to load `fontawesome5` before you use it. (Generally it is a good idea to load all packages first before doing something else in the preamble)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\title{Slides Title}
\author{Name Surname \faTwitter}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
The inclusion here of \faTwitter works fine... but including in the title or author in the titlepage produces an error (which can be solved by running over, but it is annoying).
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, you are right. Unfortunately the latex file is produced via Rmarkdown and it automatically adds \title \author etc. right after \documentclass and I can't add \usepackage{fontawesome5} before \title.
Any ideas how I can overcome this?

Comment: @LucaScrucca I think Rmarkdown lets you set a custom Pandoc template which you can use to move the `\author`.

Comment: @LucaScrucca https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/pdf-document.html#custom-templates-1